# ruby auto link username

Tags: ruby

What would be a good way to "auto link" words with @ in front of them like twitter does?
For example auto_link_user('Hello @matt please send file to harry@gmail.com') would return
'Hello [@matt](http://twitter.com/matt) please send file to harry@gmail.com'

I'm trying to do exactly this in Ruby http://www.ideone.com/aGklx

Comment: @somename should point to twitter or your local app's user?

Comment: @Naren - We'd like the solution to be flexible, similar to the link I posted, i.e. http://www.ideone.com/aGklx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str = "@foo, I'm @bar. My email is bar@bar.com"
r = /(^|\s)@([a-z0-9_]+)/i

str.gsub(r){|x| "#{$1}<a href=\"http://wwww.twitter.com/#{$2}\">@#{$2}<a/>"}
#=> "<a href=\"http://wwww.twitter.com/foo\">@foo<a/>, I'm <a href=\"http://wwww.twitter.com/bar\">@bar<a/>. My email is bar@bar.com"
```

Using [String#gsub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001186)

Comment: @Mike Lewis - how to auto link the string like str = "hi this is #sample code posted by @username". how to link both the username and #hash tag

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for direct linking into Twitter (it's not clear from your question if this is what you're trying to do) then you should look at their [@anywhere](http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere/begin) API.

**EDIT**: You could then, instead of doing it in ruby, do what you want to do with Javascript on the client side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    twttr.anywhere(function (T) {
        T("#linkify-this-content").linkifyUsers();
    });
</script>
```

It's not exactly what you were looking for, it seems, but it's an option.

Comment: Did you visit the link I posted?

Comment: Okay. I'll leave the answer up incase it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

generalize way with base url,

```
def append_urls str, base_url

str.gsub!(/(^|\s|\b)@([a-z0-9_]+)/i) do |word|
  word = $2
"<a href='#{base_url}#{word}'>#{word}</a>"
end

end
```

add this method to one of helper and invoke in view as

```
  <%= append_urls(str_to_append_url,"www.twitter.com/") %>
```